# How to use request.GET in Django models

Tags: python, django

I want to use "request" data (i.e. [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects)) in a model. Is this possible?

**models.py**:

```
[...]
from django.http import *
[...]

    class cat_1(models.Model):
            nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
            descrizione = models.CharField(max_length=255,  null=True, blank=True)
            seo_id = models.SlugField(max_length=255,  unique="True",  verbose_name="Tutto in minuscolo, sostituire spazi con trattino - ")
            livello_0 = models.ManyToManyField("cat_0",  null=True, blank=True,  verbose_name="Livello 0")

            def selezionati(self):
                Get_Data = request.GET 
                return Get_Data
```

this is the error:

> Exception Type: AttributeError at /categorie/pesce/ Exception Value:
>   'module' object has no attribute 'GET'

Comment: Models are about saving data to the database. The controller (your view) should be - and *is* - the only thing handling the request. It's not exactly MVC due to the request-response nature of HTTP but it's close. For best practices, see the official tutorial - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: @karthikr In this case, `self` is a model, it doesn't have a `request` attribute.

Comment: Bad news, i have to change all... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you really *need* request in model instance you should inject it from view before using like this:

```
class cat_1(models.Model):
    ...

    def inject_request(self, request):
        self.request = request

def some_view(request):

    my_model = cat_1()
    my_model.inject_request(request)
    ...
```

But your code shows you don't need it.